# Speeding up walletnotify

Tags: bitcoind, wallet-notify

In the case of a notice at 0 confirmations, I'm seeing the transaction end up on blockchain.info a lot faster than bitcoind is calling the walletnotify callback - about 10 minutes faster. Is it possible to speed this up?

Comment: How well connected is your node? 10 minutes is a long delay

Comment: is your wallet synced? because bitcoind send the notification once they received your transaction. make sure your bitcoind is synced.

Comment: Yes, it seems to be synched (blockcount is accurate).

Comment: @RaghavSood 124 from getconnectioncount

Comment: When you see the transaction on blockchain.info, are you sure the transaction is not in bitcoin already? Is it possible that whatever is being called just takes a long time to respond?

Comment: I'd suggest log a timestamped message with the callback, and the exact message as well to see its `confirmations`. Also test with sending bitcoin, in which case, `walletnotify` is called twice with `confirmations=0`, and once with `confirmations=1`. See if there's any delay. You could also test with `blocknotify` and log the timestamp when you receive the block containing your transaction. It'd be odd that `blocknotify` is triggered but your `walletnotify` is not